# How to Check every time if user session is expired in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, session

Check every time if Session has expired and if yes then redirect to home page by using  JavaScript such as  facebook do if I press  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> then it shows login window. I am using .aspx web pages and using WCF services

Comment: need more info if you want session then you need something like servlet /jsp etc.. what are you using , if not of any just javascript and html you may use cookie but its not recommended

Comment: You should never implement access control in javascript.

Comment: Check every time what happens?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is the best solution, but here's a solution that will test every 500 milliseconds if the user session has expired

Checker permanently a session variable with "setInterval" function every 500 milliseconds :

```
    function CheckSession() {
                var session = '<%=Session["username"] != null%>';
                //session = '<%=Session["username"]%>';
                if (session == false) {
                    alert("Your Session has expired");
                    window.location = "login.aspx";
                }
            }

setInterval(CheckSession(),500);
```

See here : http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/362898/check-for-session-timeout-in-javascript-and-redirect-to-login-page#

Comment: I done Same but when i deleted history, Session value not got expired ,It show session value in   alert in every n second in setInterval

Comment: It will not work at least because JavaScript code is generated once during ASP.NET page rendering. It means that "<%=Session["username"] != null%>" will be replaced with "true" or "false" once and then will not be updated.

Answer (score -1):

you could write a php file to check whether session has expired , if expired then header must be given argument as Location:homepage
this file must be included in each of your page by adding the
"include'filename.php'" or "require once" function

Answer (score -1):

You can basically check on page load if any of your session variables which is supposed to have a value is null or not. If the session variable is null then redirect page.